# Load specific HTML by using cheerio in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I need to get all `<a>` tag url from given webpage. And also I need to avoid `<a>` tag between header and footer tags. I am loading body tag html but without header tag. Here is my code but it doesn't work.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
$ = cheerio.load($('body').not('header'));

var links = $("a']");
links.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

If above code is wrong please suggest how to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did like this now its working fine ... Can any one tell me is this right way do this ?...

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
var t = $('body');
t.children('header').remove();
t.children('footer').remove();
var t = $.html(t);
var $ = cheerio.load(t);
var links = $("a");
links.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Cheerio works just like jQuery.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
var links = $('body').not('header').find('a');
// $('body:not(header) a') may also work.

links.each(function() {
    console.log(this.href);
});
```

Comment: This is also not removing header tag

Comment: You don't need to change the DOM to avoid checking the header.

Comment: var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var t = $('body');
    t.children('header').remove();
    t.children('footer').remove();
    var t = $.html(t);
    var $ = cheerio.load(t);

i did this its working fine

Comment: Or just ignore me, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error was because you weren't loading the HTML in your second load.  You were loading the body object. You should be able to do it this way:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
$ = cheerio.load($('body').html());

$('header').remove();

console.log($.html());
```

Comment: Sorry about that.  I was testing in the browser at first. This is working now.